# Uploading Files to Web Hosted Server not working but works on local machine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, server, hosting, web-hosting

Currently, the user uploads a barcode file to the server and then the server decodes this and send a response back to the client. This all works fine when I run the web application on my local machine, but when I publish it to my web hosting (Gear Host), it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

Client Side:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label class="btn btn-default btn-file btn-lg">
        Start Audit
        <input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera" name="file" id="file" onchange="this.form.submit();" style="display: none;">
    </label>
</form>
```

Server side:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Temp"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);

            // create a barcode reader instance
            IBarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
            // load a bitmap
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(path);

            Bitmap resized = new Bitmap(bitmap, new Size(400, 400));

            // detect and decode the barcode inside the bitmap
            var result = reader.Decode(resized);

            // Delete file once we have finished with it
            /*if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(path);
            }*/

            // do something with the result
            if (result != null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("../Room/" + result.Text);
                //txtDecoderType.Text = result.BarcodeFormat.ToString();
                //txtDecoderContent.Text = result.Text;

            }

            // Decode error
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }

        // File error
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }      
    }
```

Any help is appreciated, is this something I need to contact my hosting about?

Comment: Check directory permissions for the IIS process/user

Comment: I've look at the IIS Express System Tray and IIS Express Worker Process on my local machine and under all application packages and all restricted application packages it only had read and read and execute, then under admin it has all permissions?

Comment: @MarkSpencer error messages where? Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: @MarkSpencer it just defaults to a generic error page.